# How to change video (and start playing immediately) in Flowplayer via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

It should change the video and start playing regardless of whether or not a video is currently loaded and playing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out the javascript api for the flowplayer [here](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/api/index.html)

Specifically, you'll probably want to check out the flowplayer objects 'Clip' and 'Player'

Answer (score 6):

See example below where api is your flowplayer instance and replaceclip is the one you want to start plating

```
var api = flashembed("player", {src:'FlowPlayerDark.swf'}, {config: ...}});
var replaceclip = {'url':'myvideo.mp4', 'autoplay':true};

<button onClick="api.playClip(replaceclip)">Play</button>
```

Comment: Got it working with api.play(replaceclip) rather than api.playClip(replaceclip);

Comment: Does your code use a different version of flowplayer?  I have the latest, and it doesn't support playClip.  If you'd like to confirm that your code works with the current version of flowplayer, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I'm getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<d> has no method 'playClip'" when I try this. Tried the play() method, but got the same result.

Comment: @Larsenal @Alexandre I've had issues like that before and it is usually a scoping issue. Try changing `var api` to `window.api` and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

See my example in Github https://github.com/Teaonly/android-eye/blob/master/assets/droideye.js

```
var initAudioPlayer = function () {
    // install flowplayer into container
    // http://flash.flowplayer.org/

    $f("player", "flowplayer-3.2.15.swf", {
        plugins: {
            controls: {
                fullscreen: false,
                height: 30,
                autoHide: false,
                play: false,
            }
        },
        clip: {
            autoPlay: false,
            url: "stream/live.mp3",
        }
    });

    audioPlayer = $f();
};

var newClip = {'url':'stream/live.mp3?id='+audioCount,'autoplay':true};
audioCount ++;
audioPlayer.play(newClip);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $f().play([{url:'yourmovie.flv'}]);
```

In this way you can change the video dynamically in Ajax.